# global variable not being changed on internal function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, printing, global-variables

I've made this code that's actually working.
I want that the glogal variable "printestado" changes by the function "successors" to be printed on the function "print solution"
Here's part of the code

```py
import math
printestado = 'test'

def successors(estado_atual):
    children = [];
    if estado_atual.barco == 'esquerda':
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 2, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 2)
        printestado = 'not test 01'
        ## Dois missionários cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 2, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 2, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'not test 02'
        ## Dois canibais cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        printestado = 'not test 03'
        ## Um missionário e um canibal cruzam da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq, estado_atual.missio_esq - 1, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir, estado_atual.missio_dir + 1)
        printestado = 'not test 04'
        ## Um missionário cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
        novo_estado = Estado(estado_atual.canibal_esq - 1, estado_atual.missio_esq, 'direita',
                                  estado_atual.canibal_dir + 1, estado_atual.missio_dir)
        printestado = 'not test 05'
        ## Um canibal cruza da esquerda pra direita
        if novo_estado.eh_valido():
            novo_estado.vizinho = estado_atual
            children.append(novo_estado)
return children

def print_solution(solution):
        path = []
        path.append(solution)
        vizinho = solution.vizinho
        while vizinho:
            path.append(vizinho)
            vizinho = vizinho.vizinho

        for t in range(len(path)):
            estado = path[len(path) - t - 1]
            print("\nCalculando: ")
            print ("(" + str(estado.canibal_esq) + "," + str(estado.missio_esq) \
                              + "," + estado.barco + "," + str(estado.canibal_dir) + "," + \
                              str(estado.missio_dir) + ")")
            print(printestado)
```

the code is working perfectly how it should be (it's returning me the correct string from the "print_solution" function) but somehow the variable is not being changed (it's returning to only "test")... I've not posted the entire code due to it's being relatively big

can someone might know what's the problem ?

Comment: You didn't declare printestado as global.  Put `global printestado` at the top of the function.

Comment: Another way to get "global" variable behavior is to create a class with your functions inside and use self.printestadio

Comment: @JohnGordon at any function ?

Comment: Any function that expects to update the value of printestado as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to return printestado from your function to allow the value to persist outside it's scope.

You could test this by returning printestado instead of children and seeing if that is working as expected.

Comment: returning "children" from the function is mandatory to the code to work

Comment: Yes, I'm just saying to return printestadio as a test to check my theory. Even add it as a prefix to your children if that's easier just as a test to see if you're getting the values stored within the function.

Comment: oh, it's printing like it should, but the program itself don't work